# NSPredicate crash on CONTAINS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to do a simple predicate filter on an array of objects.

The objects in the array have 2 properties, displayValue and value.  I am trying to filter based on a search string and I get a crash.

```
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayValue CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
    NSArray *results = [_data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

what exactly is incorrect about this format that it causes a `Can't use in/contains operator with collection 100 (not a collection)` crash?

Comment: Can you show how the objects in the array are defined?

Comment: they are simply allocated with data.  `MyObject *myObject = [MyObject alloc] init];   myObject.dataValue = @"dasfasfsa"

Comment: do you mean the properties in the object?

Comment: If `displayValue` is a NSString property of `MyObject` then your predicate should work. - Can you show all properties of MyObject?

Comment: displayValue is type ID.  How would I modify this to work?

Comment: What is `ID`? Do you mean `id`, or is `ID` another class that you defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem. This happens if the `displayValue` of one of the objects
is not a `NSString`, but some different type.

From your error message, I assume that you assigned an `NSNumber`, for example

```
obj.displayValue = @100;
```

somewhere in your code. The "CONTAINS" predicate works only with *strings*, so you must assign
only string values to the property.

Therefore, you should define the type of the property as
`NSString *` instead of `id`, and check the assignments to that property.

If you really need to keep the `id` type and store different kinds of objects in that property,
then you cannot use the "CONTAINS" operator in the predicate. A direct comparison
with `@"displayValue == %@"` would work, however.

**UPDATE:** As a workaround, you could use the `description` method, which converts any object
to a string, in particular it converts a `NSNumber` to its string representation. So the following could work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayValue.description CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
```

The drawback is that the exact `description` format is not documented.

Another solution could be to use a block-based predicate, where you can check the type
of each object and perform the appropriate comparison.

Comment: I can't change the assignment of displayValue without breaking things all over the place.  Since I can't use contains, is there some way to filter an array using the displayValue as id but somehow casting it as a string?

Comment: Your update seems to work.  I'll have to make a few adjustments but for the most part, that seemed to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the update, haha. The workaround is quite good